# This with object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have seen a code which is really confusing to me. I know the `this` keyword points to global context and it depends on how it is called.

The code is

```
var gameController = {
    scores  :[20, 34, 55, 46, 77],
    avgScore:null,
    players :[
        {name:"Tommy", playerID:987, age:23},
        {name:"Pau", playerID:87, age:33}
    ]
}

var appController = {
    scores  :[900, 845, 809, 950],
    avgScore:null,
    avg     :function () {

        var sumOfScores = this.scores.reduce (function (prev, cur, index, array) {
            return prev + cur;
        });

        this.avgScore = sumOfScores / this.scores.length;
    }
}
```

The confusing part is

```
this.avgScore = sumOfScores / this.scores.length;
```

I just need to know to which object the `this`  keyword points to. Is it pointing to `appController` or `gameController`?

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: You cannot strictly assume it as either, as it depends on how you call the function `appController.avg()`

Comment: can i call the function like gameController.avg() ??

Comment: I've indented your code so the nesting is a bit easier to see

Comment: @user3609223 - No. The object `gameController` does not have a property named `avg`, so you cannot.

Comment: You can use it with gameController with the Function.prototype.apply method, appController.avg.apply(gameController). It will use gameController as this, and should return the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say `appController`. You can add a `console.log(this.players)` to verify (it's `undefined` in `appController`)

Comment: have you seen the  code of the variable sumofscores...this.scores.reduce is given there ..is it same to appController.scores.reduce ?

Comment: `reduce()` is a method of the `Array` javascript object. The 2 `scores` variables are both arrays so the code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It belongs to `appController`, specifically when `appController.avg` is called.

Comment: can i call like gameController.avg() ..is it a wrong type of calling ??